# How to programmatically impose printing restrictions/DRM on PDF for confidential documents using Microsoft .NET

Tags: .net, pdf, printing, drm

I came across stackoverflow from a podcast recommendation and I'm very impressed. This is my first post. I'm a Microsoft .net developer and I'm on a project with following requirements.

1) Confidential PDF document should be displayed to user with NO OPTION TO PRINT AT ALL.
The reason to do this is the PDF's are for view only and users are not supposed to print/archive/distribute the confidential data

We have a bunch of PDF's (100's or even 1000's and more to come) that needs to be displayed like this and I'm looking for a pragrammatic solution that can be done on the fly.

I'm ware of the security tab in Acrobat Professional but that needs opening each and every file in acrobat and putting restrictions. Also new files that gets created everyday is a big problem

Is there anyway I can introduce DRM into the PDF's programmatically

Is there a good .NET API that this DRM job on the fly when an open PDF is requested and has to be presented in a restricted format with no printing available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if users can use 'print screen', they'll always be able to print.  Making it hard for them is just going to tick them off. You could make them flash objects instead of PDFs; but that's a whole 'nother level of silliness.

Comment: DRM in general is a losing battle, IMO.

Comment: Regardless of the circumvention possibilities, I am curious if there are answers to the OP's question in terms of making it a nuisance etc.

Comment: @Joe There are always answers; but the cost of implementing them outweighs any perceived benefits -- especially if you're a company that provides SaaS.  Your users knowing you employ DRM to make their lives a nuisance is going to have a net-negative effect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is a legal one, not a technical solution.  Even if they have to take a picture of the computer screen, they'll be able to print out those PDFs.  The <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> works well too.

If you introduce DRM, you're just going to upset them and fight a losing battle. Your best bet is to talk to management and have them work up a legal solution, and not a software solution.

Comment: Well its possible to print by doing some workarounds. I agree. But the goal is to discourage the users from printing. the users are all internal and they are asked not to print which they will mostly comply. but as time passes people sometimes forget what to print and what not to print. if the print option is not available it reminds them that they are not supposed to print the PDF. 
  Any free DRM/printing restriction solutions for PDF ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used a commercial product to manipulate PDF files from .NET called [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/features.htm).  It can open an existing PDF and apply security.  You may find other commercial or open source alternatives as well.

**Update:**

I am not aware of any open source projects in .NET that will allow you to do this, and a bit of searching the interwebs did not turn up anything. I am including some links to some projects in other languages that might help ([Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries), [C++](http://pdfedit.petricek.net/en/index.html)).  But, PDF4NET is $500 per developer with royalty-free runtime.  That is pretty cheap compared to even a few hours of searching and trying out alternatives, and someone is on the hook to fix the bugs or support you if you get in a scrape.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you for recommending PDF4NET. I will try use this if there are no free alternatives. Are there any free alternatives in your knowledge? Please let me know

Comment: I don't know of any open source .NET projects that will manipulate the security of documents.  There may be something for Java and there appears to be something for C++, but I don't know if any of them do what you want.  I am editing my answer with some links.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your updated answer. Please keep me posted about any free alternatives in case if you find. Once again I appreciate your time &  help